# absolutely positioned element move even in relative container

Tags: css, html

I googled and googled and checked stackoverflow and actualy I found the answer, it's logical and I understand it, but it's not working for me!
The absolute positioned divs move when I resize the browser. I put them into a relative container and still they move. There's apparently something I am doing wrong, but I need help in finding what it is.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="zgodalogotyp.png" width="240px">
    </div>
    <div id="line"></div>
    <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

and **css**:

```
#wrapper {
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    background-position: center;
    z-index: 0;
    clear: both;

}
#box {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 265px;
    right: -30px;

    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #624051;
    z-index: 10;
    clear: both;
}
#line {
    margin-top: 254px;
    height: 56px;
    width: 455px;
    background-color: #000000;
    opacity: 0.2;
    z-index: 11;
    right: -30px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

there are many more divs in my code that I have this problem with, but I used the same schemes. 
thanks in advance

Comment: They seem to be behaving the way they should based on the code: http://jsfiddle.net/dUjTH/ What is happening in this fiddle that *isn't* what you intend?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `position:fixed` instead of `absolute`?

Comment: no and no. this is the link of what I've already made: http://world-of-krzakraft.strefa.pl/brokers/brokers1georgia.html
when you resize the browser, the box floats along with the right. I wanted to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what you are trying to achive, but I'll try to guess ;) - everything moves becouse the relative positioned element has no width specified, and you are positioning those absolute elements to the right. Perhaps setting containers width solves your problem. Or simply positioning absolute elements to the left instead of right.

Comment: Yes, thank you, setting the pixel width for the container solved my problem! I wonder however why does it not apply when I set the width in percents?